# Java Swing: How to distinguish events triggered by user?

Tags: java, swing, awt

I'd like to update GUI elements (`JComboBox`, `JLabel`, etc.) from code which shouldn't trigger change event. Is it possible to find out from `java.awt.event.ActionEvent` or `java.awt.event.ItemEvent` if the change was caused by an user or by running code like this?

```
combo.setSelectedItem("my item")
```

Comment: No, at least, not unless you can set some kind of flag which would enable the event handler to ignore the particular event...

Comment: Thanks, I thought that there would be more elegant solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is: no.

But in some cases you can try to analyze the current `InputEvent`. To get it, use `EventQueue.getCurrentEvent()`. For example if user has triggered the change on clicking of another component, you can compare the component of the input event and the component of the action event (OK I know: it's unsafe. But in some cases it can help to avoid incrementing of application complexity).

Comment: What does it mean when `EventQueue.getCurrentEvent()` is null? Events are executed in EDT thread, right? Or using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` could solve it?

Comment: Probably you have a timer event or not in EDT? Always if I trigger an action by key or mouse I can get the event using EventQueue.getCurrentEvent()

Comment: ok, I've fixed that. `evt.getSource().getClass()` is always `sun.awt.X11.XToolkit` which isn't very helpful (`evt` is `java.awt.event.ItemEvent`). Which event triggers `InputEvent`?

Answer (score 0):

For a button you can get the event modifiers:
`int buttonModifiers = evt.getModifiers();`
If the button event was generated with a call to `doClick()` the modifier is 0, otherwise not.

By the way, you can find out such differences relatively easy by logging / printing using `evt.toString()`
.